# How can I resolve on state change into a controller on nested views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to perform a resolve on state change to get data I want to inject in a controller which uses "multiple" views. The reason for having nested views is because the `template/app.html` contains a `<ion-side-menu>`, and I want to resolve data inside the `<side-menu-content>`.

**CODE**

module configuration:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'template/app.html'
})
.state('app.list', {
  url: '/list',
  views: {
    'maincontainer@app': {
      controller: 'listctrl',
      templateUrl: 'template/list.html',
      resolve: {
        item: function(dataservice) {
          return dataservice.getItems();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    auth: auth
  }
});
```

controller:

```
angular.module('controller', []).controller('listctrl', 
['$scope', function($scope, items){
  console.log(items); // prints undefined
}]);
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem is that the resolved items is never injected into the controller, though the `item` function is resolved.

I've been thinking about maybe having to store the data in local storage when resolved, and getting the items back again from the controller. I'd prefer if I didn't have to go that route (pun intended).

Comment: You have  a sidebar directive in the `app` state and you want to populate it with `items`?

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: @HristoEnev No, I was just explaining why I needed the `views` param within the state. If I didn't use views for `app.list` I assume that a resolve and controller within that state would work.

Comment: you resolved `item` (singular) in the state, but injected `items` (plural) into the controller.  These aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Claies You're right. That was a typo when I "anonymized" my code. However, you got me on the right track. I had forgotten to include `'items'` before the function, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually inject the items.

```
angular.module('controller', []).controller('listctrl', 
['$scope', "items", function($scope, items){
  console.log(items); // prints undefined
}]);
```